# Random component on fitcsvm/predict

Tags: matlab, svm

I have a train dataset and a test dataset, and I train a SVM with `fitcsvm` in MATLAB. Then, I proceed to test the trained model with `predict`. I'm always using the same datasets, but I keep getting different AUCs for the same model, which makes me wonder where in the process is there a random component. Note that

1. I'm aware of the fact that formally there isn't such thing as ROC curve or AUC and
2. I'm not asking for the statistical background of the SVM problem. It is relative to the matlab implementation of the training/test algorithm. I expected to have the same results because the training algorithm is, afaik, a deterministic process.